# most efficient algorithm to calculate prime factors of many numbers in the range up to ~ 10^9

Tags: prime-factoring

I need to calculate prime factorizations of numbers in the range up to ~ 10^9. I evaluate ~ 10^5 to 10^6 numbers, most of them large, i.e. 10^8 .. 10^9.

I am interested in numbers with small prime factors only, i.e. in the range 2 .. 300; all others do not pass my test. Therefore I do not evaluate the complete prime factorization but stop if remaining factors are larger than 300, even if these factors are not prime but contain prime factors > 300.

The code of the function reads as follows:

```
    def calc_prime_factors(self, n):                
    factors = []  
    if (n == 1):                # no further checks on data type and range
        factors.append(1)       # I don't want to return an empty list
        return factors
    for p in Primes._primes:    # precalculated primes [2, 3 ... ~300] at class level
        if (p**2 > n):
            break
        while (n % p == 0):
            factors.append(p)
            n = n // p
    if (n > 1):
        factors.append(n)       # last factor may not be prime, but exceed limit i.e. 300
    return factors
```

I tried several Python libraries but none is as fast as this implementation.

**Original questions**: Is there any way to improve this code? Are there alternative algorithms that might be faster?

In the meantime I tried caching of factorizations but the hit rate with ~ 0.01 is very low; performance is slightly decreased (I guess due to cache overhead).

The numbers to be factored are generated as numerator and denominator of neighbored Farey fractions of fixed Farey order. If the denominator is smaller than a previously checked Farey order, the entire factorization and test is skipped. Therefore, the numbers are neither consecutive nor sorted nor random. The mechanism to generate the numbers cannot be changed.

So the original question remains the same.

Comment: The most efficient algorithms depends on whether you only need to factor one number and be done with it or to factor every number up to 10^9 and other situational aspects. You should describe more of what you are trying to do and why efficiency matters.

Comment: I did that already: "I need to calculate prime factorizations of numbers in the range up to ~ 10^9. I evaluate ~ 10^5 to 10^6 numbers, most of them large, i.e. 10^8 .. 10^9". So I do not factor every number but just a small portion like 10^5 to 10^6 numbers.

Comment: Are they consecutive? Random? Sorted? Do you have them all at once and can process them in a batch and return results in one batch, or do they come individually and you need to minimize the time for each? Why is efficiency important? Why are these being factored—there might be clues in that about whether small/medium/large factors are more or less common, which might affect what algorithm we want to use (find the most likely factors first). There is no single algorithm that is the most efficient for all situations.

Comment: The numbers are generated as numerator and denominator of neighbored Farey fractions of fixed Farey order. If the denominator is smaller than a previously checked Farey order, the entire factorization and test is skipped. Therefore, the numbers are neither consecutive nor sorted nor random. The mechanism to generate them cannot be changed. In the meantime I tested caching of all intermediate results; it seems to improve the performance for smaller numbers (better hit rate) but has no effect on larger ones (it slows down slightly due to the cache).